# How do I get my simple guessing game to work?

Tags: java, string, swing

It's my second day of learning Java and I have created a simple guessing game, where you have to try and guess the 'magic word', however every time I run it, when I type the correct word it always comes up with 'Wrong!'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package textpac;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class textclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the magic word?");
    String outputText = null;
    if (inputText == "themagicword"){
        outputText = "Well done!";
    } 
    if (inputText != "themagicword"){
        outputText = "Wrong!";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputText);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing Strings, use the `.equals(...)` method instead of the `==` operator:

```
if (inputText.equals("subscribe")){
    outputText = "Well done!";
} 
if (!(inputText.equals("themagicword"))){
    outputText = "Wrong!";
}
```

The problem is that `==` compares if a String variable's reference or *object* is the exact same as that of another String variable's, and that is not what you want to know. Instead you want to know if the two String objects share the same letters, in the same order, with the same capitalization, and for that, use the `.equals(...)` method or `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` if capitalization isn't important.

Comment: **Additional information** Strings are objects in Java. So when you compare strings, you check if objects are equivalent. So if you want to compare values of strings, it's better to use String.equals() method.

Comment: "Text".equalsIgnoreCase(variable) would prevent the possibility of null pointer exceptions ;)

Comment: You could use `else` instead of doing the comparison twice.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, glad i could help as well